# SOAP XML response using cURL and PHP cisco CUCM API

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap, cucm

I'm trying to pull data from a SOAP API (Call manager CISCO) using CURL in PHP with POSTMAN tool like this
:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'url',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:getUser sequence="?">
            <userid>apiUser</userid>
        </ns:getUser>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Basic ..',
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

So it is working fine but i get a full string response when i do echo $response like :

```
updatedtestApiapiaddUserTestapiaddUserTestapiaddUserTestapiUser....
```

Instead of the XML string that i got when i var_dump($response) :

```
'<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:getUserResp.....
```

Basically what i want to do is to access my XML values like   in PHP, i tried using simplexml_load_string i got an empty string and also SimpleXMLElement() and also got an empty object..

How can i work with it ? what i am doing wrong

Comment: Have you already tried to set the accept header? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept , https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html

Answer (score 0):

You need both content-type header and accept http request header

```
$request[] = 'Content-Type: application/xml';
$request[] = 'Accept: application/xml';
$request[] = 'Authorization: Basic';
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $request
```

With out the `Content-Type: application/xml` the Content-Type will be `multipart/form-data` and curl will attempt to put the JSON in the $_POST.  
When you specify application/xml the xml will be passed in the request body. 
If you are supposed to send the parameters as form data then you must convert the xml to an array.

You do not need

```
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST'
```

Just use

```
 CURLOPT_POST => true
```

If you want to see the response header in your `$response`, add this.  Look at the Content-Type in the response header.

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => true
```